# Checking that a value of one integer type fits into another

Tags: c, types, type-conversion

There are two types `Type1` and `Type2` provided by different headers, which are both typedefs for some integer types but it isn't known which (and may be different across compilers, OSes, etc. anyway). Is this program guaranteed to work correctly (if it compiles)

```
Type1 a = ...;
if (a == (Type2) a) {
  printf("a fits into Type2");
else {
  printf("a doesn't fit into Type2");
}
```

or are there corner cases I am not taking into account?

Answer (score 3):

If you're only worried about the *size* of the entry, use `sizeof`:

```
if (sizeof(a) == sizeof(Type2)) {
  printf("a fits into Type2");
else {
  printf("a doesn't fit into Type2");
}
```

Comment: Yes, and use a compile-time assert for checking that.

Comment: No, not the size. I want to know if the value can be represented correctly. E.g. `4294967295` fits into `unsigned int` or `long long` but doesn't fit into `int` on 32 bit platform.

Comment: Of course, this also means that this can't be decided at compile-time since it depends on the actual value of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think unfortunately this is not enough. If e.g `Type1` is `short` and `Type2` is `int` the value on the left still would be promoted to `int`. So you are comparing the same value of the same type.

Also ensuring to do the comparison both ways would not help in general.

What you'd have to do is to ensure that you do the comparison both ways *and* that the value that you cast is a value that would be truncated if casted to a narrower type. If both are unsigned types you could use something like

```
((T1)-1 == (T1)(T2)(T1)-1) && ((T2)-1 == (T2)(T1)(T2)-1)
```

This also has the advantage of being a compile time expression.

If one or both of the types are signed, this is way more difficult because of the different sign representations that are allowed in C.

**Edit:** When I wrote that I somehow overlooked that you only wanted that in one direction.

```
(T1)-1 == (T1)(T2)(T1)-1
```

just tells you if there is loss of information when casting from `T1` to `T2`.

Comment: "If e.g `Type1` is `short` and `Type2` is `int` the value on the left still would be promoted to `int`. So you are comparing the same value of the same type." But any `short` value _can_ be represented as `int`, so this give me the desired result.

Comment: See also my comment to Nathan's answer; the result very much depends on the actual value of `a`, so it can't be found at compile time.

Comment: @Alexey, this was just meant as an example. If you invert the role of `int` and `short` you don't get away as easily. Also really be careful cause your solution also depends on the initial value of `a`.

Comment: "If you invert the role of `int` and `short` you don't get away as easily." Can you give an example when it fails? I.e. `a` is small enough to be represented as `short`, but the comparison returns `false`, or too large but the comparison returns `true`?