# How to check if value will fit into type?

Tags: c, types, overflow

Let's assume I have a type name called  `T` and its size always is `>=` `T2` both are unsigned. How do I check if a variable `a` of type `T` will fit into `T2` without overflow and if it didn't fit do some other operation? I've tried check if it's became negative but I'm not sure if it's right way to check, like this:

```
T a = ...;
T2 b = a;
if(b < 0) // didn't fit
else // ok, fit
```

Comment: if T2 is unsigned b will always be >= 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking that a value of one integer type fits into another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4142557) (but that doesn't have a good answer).

Comment: Using the library limits you can know if certain value is in range:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

Answer (score 1):

This won't work: if `T` and `T2` are unsigned, `b < 0` will always be false.

Since both of these types are unsigned, it is guaranteed that overflow causes wrap around (side note: if these were signed types, overflowing would cause UB, although it *usually* wraps around too). Thus, you can use something like:

```
T a = ...;
T2 b = a;
if ((T) b != a) {
   /* didn't fit */
}
else { ... }
```

The cast around `b` is not strictly necessary: if `sizeof(T)` > `sizeof(T2)`, then the usual arithmetic conversions cause `b` to be converted to `T` before comparing to `a`. However, to make it clear, I chose to explicitly leave it there.

According to section 6.3.1.3 on C99 (see comments below), this is what happens when an unsigned integer is converted to a narrower unsigned type:

> if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly
>   adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be
>   represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new
>   type

This means that in case of overflow, `b` will not be equal to `a` when converted back to `T`. That's the rationale behind this code. Moreover, it will be *less* than `a`, so you can switch `!=` to `<` if you prefer.

Alternatively, you can check before assigning to `b` to make sure it will fit:

```
T a = ...;
T2 b;

if (a > (T2)-1) {
    /* won't fit */
}
else {
    /* fits */
}
```

`(T2) -1` is the maximum value that the unsigned type `T2` can hold. If `a` is greater than this, then it won't obviously fit into `b`. To see why `(T2) -1` is portable and always work, see this question: [Is it safe to use -1 to set all bits to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true)

Comment: I know that in practice `(T2)~0ULL` is the maximum value the unsigned type `T2` can hold, but... is this guaranteed by the standard? Just playing the devil's advocate

Comment: Why do you say that the cast around `b` is necessary? AFAIK, it is not, per **6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**

Comment: I'll try to answer my first question: according to **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**, _if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type_, which does **not** guarantee that `(T2)~0ULL` is the maximum value the unsigned type `T2` can hold

Comment: About your 2nd question: the cast is in fact unnecessary, since the usual arithmetic conversions will convert `b` to `T` if in fact `sizeof(T) > sizeof(T2)`.

Comment: @WalterTross About your 1st question: you're right. I didn't even think about this rule, I basically assumed that the cast would narrow `~0ULL` down to the size of `T`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
T  a = ...;
T2 b = a;
if (b < a) // didn't fit
else // ok, fit
```

Just one byte away from what you wrote :-)

This works because for unsigned types an overflow always generates a smaller value, and the comparison will only convert `b` to `T`, which is unproblematic.

From the C99 standard (**6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**):

> [...] if the new type is unsigned, the value is
>   converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the
>   maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value
>   is in the range of the new type.

This also means that the solution by Joseph Quinsey is correct: you can always compare `a` to `(T2)-1`, which is guaranteed to be the maximum value the unsigned type `T2` can hold:

```
if (a > (T2)-1)) // won't fit
```

Please note that the standards never speaks of "sizes" (except when talking about `sizeof`), in order to remain general. Of course, the iterative procedure I cited boils down to truncating high order bits probably in all contemporary architectures, but you never know...

Comment: *It is guaranteed to work only if T and T2 are both signed or unsigned* This is not true. Overflowing on signed types causes UB as per the C standard rules.

Comment: sorry @FilipeGonçalves, I have completely rewitten my answer before your comment - anyways, you are right

Answer (score 0):

Because `T2` is unsigned, your `if (b < 0)` will *not* work. The following should be ok:

```
    T a = ...;
    T2 b;
    if (a > (T2)-1) // a won't fit into a T2
       //...
    else
       b = a; // safe, no overflow, value unchanged
```

You need `-1` rather than `~0`, because the latter is an `int`, and won't work if `T2` is wider than an `int`. (But `~0LL` will work for all the usual types.)

I believe that for an unsigned type `T2`, its maximum value is always `(T2)-1`. From the C99 standard:

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
>   the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.<sup>49)</sup>
>
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

So, for example, if the maximum value of `T2` is `10`, then `(T2)-1` is evaluated by adding `11` to `-1`, to get `10`, as desired.

See also [Question about C behaviour for unsigned integer underflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760502/question-about-c-behaviour-for-unsigned-integer-underflow/2760612#2760612) and [Is it safe to assign -1 to an unsigned int to get the max value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310771/is-it-safe-to-assign-1-to-an-unsigned-int-to-get-the-max-value/10310789#10310789) and [Signed to unsigned conversion in C - is it always safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe/50632#50632).

Comment: **Edit:** The best reference is [Is it safe to use -1 to set all bits to true?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/809341).

Answer (score -1):

I've placed some pseudocode here to help. You should be able to get the answer from that pseudocode by tidying it up.

What you want to do is check all of the bits that are > the number of bits in T2. If any of them are "1", you can't store that particular T variable safely in a T2.

```
// If T is an int (32 bits) and T2 is a char (8 bits):
// assume variable a is the integer in question.

int mask = 0;
for (int i = sizeof(T2); i < sizeof(T); ++i)
{
    int mask = 1 << i;
    if (a & mask)
    {
        // if this hits, we have a "1" in that bit, so the value cannot fit.
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```